How to copy all the events from one calendar to another calendar?
I have a calendar named "CalendarA" I would like to copy all the events to "CalendarB". I have tried exporting CalendarA and then importing the events into CalendarB, but those events eventually disappear. I have also tried copy / paste events, but repeat events are not correctly copied. (Copies as single events w/o repeating.) I have also tried calendar archive, but that is more a backup and doesn't work.
I don't want to move the events. Both Calendars are iCloud connected.

What if you do a select all in CalendarA and drag it to the desktop. This gives you an .ics file that you can than drag into any calendar window like your CalendarB.
